# webpack splitchunks import chunks

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bundle

I have a folder one and some files import modules. now I use splitChunks.cacheGroups.test like this

```
test: (module) => {
    return (
       /src[\\/]one[\\/]/i.test(module.context)
    );
},
```

but if I use test I can't bundle modules in one.

It has any way fix it?

Thanks!